# Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css, how to get to the second one?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am having problems in Capybara with the Ambiguous match problem. And the page provides no 'ids" to identify which one is which.

I am using within function.

```
within('.tile.tile-animation.animation-left.animation-visible.animated') do 
    #some code in here
end
```

I've used the :match option which solved my first problem.

```
within('.tile.tile-animation.animation-left.animation-visible.animated', :match => :first) do 
    #some code in here
end
```

The question is how to get to the SECOND css '.tile.tile-animation.animation-left.animation-visible.animated' ?

Comment: How about little more `html` code. I believe `nth-child()` function can be the solution

Comment: the code looks identical except  what's between the <div>  ... </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the html -- a simple solutions is

```
within(all('.tile.tile-animated.animation-left.animation-visible.animated')[1]) do
 # some code in here
end
```

which will scope to the second matching element on the page, but won't be able to auto-reload if the page changes, and won't wait for the elements to appear.  If you need it to wait for at least two elements to appear you can do

```
within(all('.tile.tile-animated.animation-left.animation-visible.animated', minimum: 2)[1]) do
....
```

which will wait some time for at least the 2 elements to appear on the page, but still won't be able to auto-reload if the page changes.   If you need the ability to auto-reload on a dynamically changing page it will need to be possible to write a unique selector for the element (rather than indexing into the results of `#all`.

Comment: hi Tom, just wondering if the [1] indicates which CSS the code is pointing to?

Comment: @Ben [1]  gets the second element of the array returned by #all

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so this question gets marked as answered. Thanks!